# Install ZeroSSL certificates on AWS ELB HTTPS listener for Keycloak deployed on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-application-load-balancer, zerossl

I want to add a certificate on my HTTPS listener in AWS ELB with a wildcard (keycloak.website.com) from zerossl.

I imported the certificate in ACM and use it on the listener.
[image: AWS Certificate manager - Certificate Status]
But it seems like I messed something but don't know where.

Here are my rules on the listeners:
[image: Listener's rules]

PS: I deployed the keycloak on ECS and I can access it from the HTTP but when I want to login to the admin dashboard I got the HTTPS error page like this:
[image: Keycloak Error]

Comment: Did you configure the HTTP listener to redirect to HTTPS? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Comment: Yes @jordanm I did

Comment: Keycloak is unaware of the SSL connection, because the SSL connection is between your web browser and the load balancer. The connection between the load balancer and the ECS instance is unencrypted HTTP.  You need to configure Keycloak to check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to determine the encryption status.

Comment: I fixed the issues. I added the CNAME record on the Cpanel dashboard and it works now.. Thanks anyone who tried to help.